# Universal Analaytics with redirect

Tags: google-analytics

I have set up a page that redirects to our app store download page. I use the page to provide custom meta headers for sharing to facebook/twitter etc. However, I would like to implement google analytics on the page. Currently, GA does not appear to fire properly using the following code:

```
    <script>
        (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
        m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
        })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
        ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX', 'auto');
        ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
        ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.location.href = "https://itunes.apple.com/......"
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're likely redirecting before the analytics call is finished. I'd suggest using the [hitCallback function](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#hitCallback) with a timeout as a fallback.

Very simple example:

```
<script>
    var redirectCallback = function() {
        window.location.href = "https://itunes.apple.com/......"
    };

    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX', 'auto');
    ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
    ga('send', 'pageview', {
        'hitCallback': redirectCallback
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // Redirect after 2 seconds in case the analytics call didn't finish
    window.setTimeout(redirectCallback, 2000);
</script>
```